# Prove that every non-zero element of a finite commutative ring with unity is either a zero-divisor or a unit.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let *R* be a finite commutative ring with unity. Prove that every non-zero element of *R* is either a zero-divisor or a unit. What happens if we drop the "finite" condition on *R* ?

Comment: For the infinite case: Look at $\mathbb Z$, what are its zero divisors? Its units?

Comment: I don't understand why this question have 3 votes down? +1

Comment: Guys, look at the user's history. Pretty much we are doing the OPs homework...

Comment: @LuisValerin: See Luis's comment.

Comment: Is true you are right.

Comment: sorry, I voted to delete my post.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Don't apologise. Just check next time when it is a question that is just stated with no effort. Especially when it is a question that has probably been asked a trillion times =]. I did the same thing and learnt my lesson.

Comment: Why assume the ring is commutative?

Comment: Okay, apologies for apologizing. ;-)